# Need help setting up a font

Tags: 18.04, fonts

[The font I want to use is a patched Inconsolata font](https://github.com/realestninja/Dotfiles/blob/master/fonts/Inconsolata%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.otf). I was using it in gnome-terminal on ubuntu 17.04.

On ubuntu 18.04 I can't choose it as a monospace font. The font is installed and I can choose it in libreoffice for example, so it's definitely there.

What I did next: I used `font-manager` to check the font's properties. I noticed that the 'Spacing' property says 'Proportional' instead of 'Monospace'.

How can I fix this, or how can I use this font as a terminal font in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The font was wrongly patched and therefor not recognized as a monospace font even though being a monospace font. I traced back from where I had downloaded it earlier this year and found a solution at the github-issues section: https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/issues/270#issuecomment-394312962

With dconf-editor it is possible to just type in the font gnome-terminal is suppossed to use.